# COM('word.document') open in read only whilst file is opened by other

Tags: php, com, ms-word

I'm using php and try to fiddle around with COM objects to read Word files. I am getting litereally nowhere with finding documentation.

What I want to do is open a file in read only so I dont get the "File is in use" popup on the host computer.

How do I tell word via COM to open the file as read only? I am trying to use variants but I get the following error:

`Parameter 0: Type mismatch. #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php(17): variant->Open('\\remote\test\test.doc', false, true, false, Object(variant), Object(variant), Object(variant), Object(variant), Object(variant), Object(variant), Object(variant), true, true, Object(variant), Object(variant), true) #1 {main}`

This is the code I use

```
$word = new COM("word.application") or die("Unable to instantiate application object");

$wordDocument = new COM("word.document") or die("Unable to instantiate document object");
$MISSING =  new VARIANT();

$word->Visible = 0;
$DocumentPath = "\\remote\test\test\alamo.doc";
$HTMLPath = "";
try {
$wordDocument = $word->Documents->Open("\\exit-dc\eeb\test\alamo.doc"/* FileName */, false/* ConfirmConversions */, true/* ReadOnly */, 
                                    false/* AddToRecentFiles */, $MISSING/* PasswordDocument */, $MISSING/* PasswordTemplate */, 
                                    $MISSING/* Revert */, $MISSING/* WritePasswordDocument */, $MISSING/* WritePasswordTemplate */, 
                                    $MISSING/* Format */,$MISSING/* Format */, $MISSING/* Encoding */, true/* Visible */, true/* OpenConflictDocument */, 
                                    $MISSING/* OpenAndRepair */, $MISSING/* DocumentDirection */, true/* NoEncodingDialog */);

$HTMLPath = substr_replace($DocumentPath, 'html', -3, 3);
if($wordDocument !== null) {
    $wordDocument->SaveAs($HTMLPath, 3);//3 = text, I know.
}
}
catch(Exception $ex){
    echo $ex->getMessage() . $ex->getTraceAsString();
}
$wordDocument = null;

$word->Quit();

$word = null;
```

What i want? To open the file with the read only flag. I only want to read from it. I know I can do that by providing the filename only, that works, but I need it to work with multiple instances reading the same file.

For all intents and purposes this should work. Php should cast the string and booleans to the proper Variant types and the empty variant types should fill the place of `System.Reflection.Missing.Value`

I used https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835182(v=office.14).aspx (Word 2010) to compile the list of arguments needed, and reading through the comments on http://php.net/manual/en/book.com.php to find a workable solution...

The only solution that seems to work so far is making a copy, open that, read it, delete the copy. For me thats the least desirable option because this should you know, work. Plenty of C++, vb, .net etc... examples of how this works, but php simply refuses to accept the parameters. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digging some more, having tested many things that failed I finally found a solution to open in read only, and I found two ways to rome, so I'm posting them both.

By leaving out the surplus values it suddenly works. Still leaves me with the question what to use as a "null" in this case so I can skip that variable. But thats a worry for another time. I don't need that yet.

**Via DOTNET Object**

```
$assembly = 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c';
$class = 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass';

$w = new DOTNET($assembly, $class);
$w->visible = true;
$DocumentPath = "\\\\remote\\test\\alamo.doc";
$d = $w->Documents->Open($DocumentPath,false,true);
echo "Document opened.<br><hr><PRE>";
com_print_typeinfo($d);

$w->Quit();
$w=null;
```

**Via COM Object**

```
$DocumentPath = "\\\\remote\\test\\alamo.doc";
$word = new COM("word.application") or die("Unable to instantiate application object");

$wordDocument = new COM("word.document") or die("Unable to instantiate document object");
$MISSING =  1;

$word->Visible = true;

$HTMLPath = "";
try {
echo "<PRE>";
com_print_typeinfo($word->Documents);
echo "</PRE>";
$wordDocument = $word->Documents->Open($DocumentPath/* FileName */,
                                     false/* ConfirmConversions */, 
                                        true/* ReadOnly */);

$HTMLPath = substr_replace($DocumentPath, 'html', -3, 3);
if($wordDocument !== null) {
    $wordDocument->SaveAs($HTMLPath, 3);
}
}
catch(Exception $ex){
    echo $ex->getMessage() . $ex->getTraceAsString();
}
$wordDocument = null;

$word->Quit();

$word = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

just one question why use com, which is not recommended for use on the server specifically in the context of php you should instead try reading word 2007/2010 .docx files which are nothing but xml files and avoid all the hassels all together

Comment: The files I read are in doc format. I am willing to convert them to docx, I can put some cheap labour on that, but could you point me to an api that reads docx? so far all I found was again COM

Comment: And, i'd prefer using the Com object because it makes conversion to PDF a whole lot easier.

Comment: i can point you to code that reads xlsx files , which should give you a head start